# C# How to get an access to public service field or method from other service?

Tags: c#, api, service

I have a service, and I need to get its public field from other service. Code of this service:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly string strConfigXmlFileName = StartupObject.DEFAULT_CONFIG_XML;
    private StartupObject _startupObject;
    private readonly string serviceName = "My Service";

    // this field is changed into service, we need to get its actual value
    public string testString;

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _startupObject = new StartupObject(strConfigXmlFileName);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // For Designer only:
        ServiceName = "MyService";
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_service != null)
            _service.Dispose();
        _service = null;

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _startupObject.startAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // some logging
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            _startupObject.stopAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // some logging
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this field testString from other project?

I know how to get ServiceController for it and start it if it wasn't runned, maybe there is a way to get ServiceBase from ServiceController?

Comment: why can't you just create an instance of this class and access it's public field?

Comment: I need to connect to already created and runned process. "testString" is for example

Comment: How does that matter anyways since your is a `readonly` field with static data in it?

Comment: ok, I changed this part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly depends on a context and tools available but I will try to answer this question based on my own assumptions. By "Service" here I assume a process instance rather than object instance.

1) This string is readonly/constant - I would suggest to store it in a small database or a configuration file shared across applications and read this configuration key when starting up both applications.

2) You can also try to store this setting in a shared memory. More info is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files).

Windows Virtual Memory will not allow you to access this variable from other process easily.

Comment: ok, I changed this part of code. I want to get some public field from the first service, and this field was changed somewhere in this service

Comment: If this field is changeable the simplest solution is to use messaging protocol. AMPQ for instance. But it also depends on ability to change the code of first service.

Comment: When the field value is changed - the message should be published from the first process and then consumed in the second one. The message payload is obviously a field value.

Comment: Thank you, as I understand, it's the best way.